# How to throw an error when set_jsonb doesn't update a key?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

I am running this query in psycopg2:

```
"UPDATE accounts SET user_settings=jsonb_set(user_settings, '{{{0}}}', to_jsonb('{1}'::text, false)) WHERE accounts.id = {2};".format(
                        key, val, account_id)
```

It's wrapped within a try/except. It seems that when a key fails to update no exceptions are thrown. I've set "create new key if key doesn't exist" to false. Is it possible to get an error thrown so I can handle it when a key fails to get updated using `set_jsonb()`?

PS. I know I shouldn't be passing in params using the python format. That's the next fix on my list. Right now I need to figure out how to handle keys not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `jsonb_set()` does not raise an exception when a key does not exist.

Use `returning` and examine the result in your code:

```
UPDATE accounts
SET user_settings=
    jsonb_set(
        user_settings, 
        '{a_key}', 
        to_jsonb('new_value'::text),
        false)
WHERE id = 1
RETURNING user_settings->>'a_key' = 'new_value';
```

The query yields `true` if and only if the key exists and has been updated.

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`returning` returns a row only if the update succeeded (the `where` clause yields `true`). Otherwise nothing will be returned. To have a value to test `union` the returning set (may be empty) to a fail row:

```
update = '''
    with u as (
        update accounts
        set user_settings = jsonb_set(
            user_settings, '{{{0}}}', to_jsonb('{1}'::text, false)
            )
        where accounts.id = {2};".format(key, val, account_id)
        returning true as updated
    )
    select updated
    from u
    union all
    select false
    order by 1 desc
'''.format(key, val, account_id)
```

The result will be either `true` or `false`

Comment: It's not true. Note that the row is updated even if the key does not exist. The query returns no rows only if `id` has not been found. And you can use simple `coalesce` for this case.

Comment: @klin Failing the `where` clause is exactly what I was referring to. And it is not trivial to coalesce a value in a row that does not exist. Check `select coalesce(null, false) where false;`

Comment: But you cannot `returning true as updated` because it also returns when the key does not exist.. And I mean `coalesce` wrapped on the whole query.

Comment: @klin Just replace with your rule to implement it. As I understand the OP did not ask for it.

Comment: The OP wrote: *when a key fails to get updated using set_jsonb()*